# pandas dataframe drop columns by number of nan

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with some columns containing nan. I'd like to drop those columns with certain number of nan. For example, in the following code, I'd like to drop any column with 2 or more nan. In this case, column 'C' will be dropped and only 'A' and 'B' will be kept. How can I implement it?

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

dff = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(10,3), columns=list('ABC'))
dff.iloc[3,0] = np.nan
dff.iloc[6,1] = np.nan
dff.iloc[5:8,2] = np.nan

print dff
```

Answer (score 37, accepted):

There is a `thresh` param for [`dropna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html#pandas.DataFrame.dropna), you just need to pass the length of your df - the number of `NaN` values you want as your threshold:

```
In [13]:

dff.dropna(thresh=len(dff) - 2, axis=1)
Out[13]:
          A         B
0  0.517199 -0.806304
1 -0.643074  0.229602
2  0.656728  0.535155
3       NaN -0.162345
4 -0.309663 -0.783539
5  1.244725 -0.274514
6 -0.254232       NaN
7 -1.242430  0.228660
8 -0.311874 -0.448886
9 -0.984453 -0.755416
```

So the above will drop any column that does not meet the criteria of the length of the df (number of rows) - 2 as the number of non-Na values.

Comment: Thanks. A typo in your code `len(df)` should be `len(dff)`

Comment: Do you know if its possible to apply thresh except for a subset of specific columns? Thank you.

Comment: @pceccon sorry but I tend to not answer questions in comments as it lacks clarity, you can subset columns by passing a list so IIUC you can do something like `df[col_name_list].fillna(...)` to only apply the thresh to this subset and to apply to the other columns `df[df.columns.difference(col_name_list)].filna(....)`

Answer (score 4):

You can use a conditional list comprehension:

```
>>> dff[[c for c in dff if dff[c].isnull().sum() < 2]]
          A         B
0 -0.819004  0.919190
1  0.922164  0.088111
2  0.188150  0.847099
3       NaN -0.053563
4  1.327250 -0.376076
5  3.724980  0.292757
6 -0.319342       NaN
7 -1.051529  0.389843
8 -0.805542 -0.018347
9 -0.816261 -1.627026
```

Comment: Is that an efficient implementation cpu wise?

Comment: Trivial for most use cases, but the answer would depend on the size of your dataframes.  The accepted answer is about 40% faster on my machine using a dataframe of 1m rows with 3 cols.

Answer (score 1):

Say you have to drop columns having more than 70% null values.

```
data.drop(data.loc[:,list((100*(data.isnull().sum()/len(data.index))>70))].columns, 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a possible solution:

```
s = dff.isnull().apply(sum, axis=0) # count the number of nan in each column
print s
   A    1 
   B    1
   C    3
   dtype: int64

for col in dff: 
   if s[col] >= 2:  
       del dff[col]
```

Or

```
for c in dff:
    if sum(dff[c].isnull()) >= 2:
        dff.drop(c, axis=1, inplace=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend the `drop`-method. This is an alternative solution:

```
dff.drop(dff.loc[:,len(dff) - dff.isnull().sum() <2], axis=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this through another approach as well like below for dropping columns having certain number of na values:

```
df = df.drop( columns= [x for x in df if df[x].isna().sum() > 5 ])
```

For dropping columns having certain percentage of na values :

```
df = df.drop(columns= [x for x in df if round((df[x].isna().sum()/len(df)*100),2) > 20 ])
```